# Building an interface from Spotfire (with its SDK) to the BO reporting environment

Tags: sdk, tibco, spotfire

I just got a new task; I need to:

"Team have an Excel spreadsheet which contains basic data about subjects in a trial. A custom VB script in the Excel sheet allows them to generate BO reports. At a very high level, they are able to select a particular cell in the Pivot table and then execute a VB script via a custom button in the Excel sheet. The script generates an XML file containing metadata about those subjects and some additional parameters such as report title and saves the XML file to a watched directory. An external process picks it up and generates a fully-formatted BO report with complete details about the identified subjects from the drug safety database, and sends it to the user as a PDF in a new browser window.

So really this is not about doing data analysis within Spotfire (including R), but it is more to do with building an interface from Spotfire to the BO reporting environment. I believe this can be done with the Spotfire SDK, which uses IronPython as its scripting language, but I cannnot say for certain because I have very little experience in that area."

Is there any chance for some high level suggestion of what approach do I have to take in order to attain the functionality requested ?

I also dont have any exp with Spotfire's tibco technical support. Do you guys think I can ask any such questions to them ?

Regards,
Jacek

Comment: Could BO output its processed file back to Excel rather than PDF, you could then open that in Spotfire with little effort.

Comment: Do you need any information/suggestions regarding the BusinessObjects side? If so, do you have an idea of the BOBJ version used and what client is used / should be used to generate the reports (Webi, CR, …)?

Comment: I'm a bit lost in your text as to what you want to achieve... Do you want a button in Spotfire that performs basically the same as currently the button in Excel on the data that you see/select in Spotfire?  Or do you want a the button in Excel to generate a Spotfire report instead of a BE report?

Comment: Miichi - I want a button in SP that performs the same what button in Excel does currently.

Comment: I have addressed the requirement by creating the ASP.NET page and embedding webplayer inside.

The webplayer contains visualization and a button. It is possible to mark data in Spotfire Web Plyaer.

Clicking the button results in invocation of a jquery method that sends marked data to the svc file. Then there is a processing done on server side programmed in C#. C# creates a query to the BO with prompt answers.

That concludes the requirement.